# Installing dart-sass/node-sass into a Meteor/Vue project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, meteor, sass

To use `SASS` in my Vue/Meteor project I would run `meteor add akryum:vue-sass`. This is now failing as it seems `node-sass` cannot be found.

```
 => Errors while adding packages:

While loading package akryum:vue-sass@0.1.2:
error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\2.5.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\bin\npm.cmd rebuild --update-binary
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.12.0/win32-x64-83_binding.node": 

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g. 

export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Michael\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\2.5.1\\mt-os.windows.x86_64\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Michael\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\akryum_vue-sass\\0.1.2\\plugin.vue-component-sass.os\\npm\\node_modules\\meteor\\vue-component-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@14.18.1 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\2.5.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\python\python.exe" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\2.5.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\python\python.exe C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\2.5.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\python\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\2.5.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\python\python.exe -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                       ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:383:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:443:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:686:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Users\\Michael\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\2.5.1\\mt-os.windows.x86_64\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Michael\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\akryum_vue-sass\\0.1.2\\plugin.vue-component-sass.os\\npm\\node_modules\\meteor\\vue-component-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags="
"--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\akryum_vue-sass\0.1.2\plugin.vue-component-sass.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\vue-component-sass\node_modules\.temp-qkxkiu.ahrs\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v14.18.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-28T12_28_38_840Z-debug.log
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.12.0/win32-x64-83_binding.node": 

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g. 

export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Michael\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\2.5.1\\mt-os.windows.x86_64\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Michael\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\akryum_vue-sass\\0.1.2\\plugin.vue-component-sass.os\\npm\\node_modules\\meteor\\vue-component-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@14.18.1 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\2.5.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\python\python.exe" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\2.5.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\python\python.exe C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\2.5.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\python\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\2.5.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\python\python.exe -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                       ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:383:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:443:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:686:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Users\\Michael\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\2.5.1\\mt-os.windows.x86_64\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Michael\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\akryum_vue-sass\\0.1.2\\plugin.vue-component-sass.os\\npm\\node_modules\\meteor\\vue-component-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags="
"--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\akryum_vue-sass\0.1.2\plugin.vue-component-sass.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\vue-component-sass\node_modules\.temp-qkxkiu.ahrs\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v14.18.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-28T12_28_38_840Z-debug.log
```

How can I get `SASS` working in my Vue/Meteor project without this?